# robots.txt not updating for rails heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, caching

I've got a rails app hosted on Heroku for which I'm trying to update the robot.txt file.

Earlier, in my `production.rb` I had:

```
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=2592000"
```

But, I changed it to:

```
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=0"
```

And pushed the code again to production.

I also tried running:
`Rails.cache.clear` in `heroku rails console` but still `/robots.txt` is displaying the old file.

**EDIT:**

I have removed the 'robots.txt' file from the `public` folder.
Cleaning and precompiling the assets again, also didn't work.

I can still access it on production.

Comment: How do you do caching in your application? Do you set `config.cache_store` in `production.rb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, the caching was in my chrome browser.

When I checked the site on a different browser, `robots.txt` was updated.

So, I cleared the cache and cookies for chrome browser and refreshed the `/robots.txt` and voila! file was updated.